Reemplazar la coma en la posicion 13 por blanco, sabiendo que el campo de la descripción va despues de la coma 12
tengo una coma en la descripción, esta columna siempre esta después de la coma 12, como puedo reemplazarla con blanco U&U INTER-TRADE CO. LTD.

20000000345,EMPRESA S.R.L.,202007,2000000034501F0020000000800,31/07/2020,30/08/2020,01,F002,800,,0,30000000280,U&U INTER-TRADE CO., LTD.,999.55,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,999.55,USD,3.742,,,,,,,1,0,0,0200,,


No indicas qué tipo de dato es, pero como dices descripción asumo que se trata de un string. Si es así, una forma es aplicando un str_replace.
$data = '...800,,0,30000000280,U&U INTER-TRADE CO., LTD.,999.55...'; // La cadena
$data = str_replace('TRADE CO., LTD.', 'TRADE CO. LTD.', $data);

El resultado será:
...800,,0,30000000280,U&U INTER-TRADE CO. LTD.,999.55...

Si esa cadena es un CSV, otra opción para parsearla con todo y la coma puede ser que cuando generas esa "descripción", las sub-cadenas conflictivas vengan envueltas entre comillas dobles. En el momento de aplicar el parser, indicarle que el caracter de envoltura es ". Ver str_getcsv y fgetcsv
$data = '...800,,0,30000000280,"U&U INTER-TRADE CO., LTD.",999.55...';


Buenos días aeportugal el CSV no lo genero, lo descargo desde un servicio, entonces necesito que despues de la ',' número 12 me elimine esa coma demás que este en la descripción de esta manera igual la cantidad de columnas con los demas registros gracias

Siendo la cadena un string puedes probar esto:
<?php
    $str = "20000000345,EMPRESA S.R.L.,202007,2000000034501F0020000000800,31/07/2020,30/08/2020,01,F002,800,,0,30000000280,U&U INTER-TRADE CO., LTD.,999.55,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,999.55,USD,3.742,,,,,,,1,0,0,0200,,";

    echo $str . "<br><br>"; // (solo para probar)

    // Encontrar la posición de la coma número 12
    $pos = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($str, ',', $pos) + 1;
    }

    //Cambiar ',' por espacio en blanco
    $new_str = substr_replace($str, ' ', $pos - 1, 1);

    echo $new_str;
?>

Donde como resultado tendríamos esto:

Te anexo un enlace para que lo pruebes tú mismo: PHP Playground

Gracias PsychoMx por la solución funciono correctamente
